# Tinkerpop - how do I find a node in the graph?

Tags: graph, gremlin, orientdb

I can't seem to find a specific node in the graph without traversing the whole thing. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using tinkerpop blueprints.

Orientdb gives some sort of unsemantic id to a node such as '#8:1' - how do I find this without knowing the id? vertex has a property like 'user=jason' that will identify it.
I'm thinking I'll just use redis to store the user/location pair or otherwise use a supernode (no thanks)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blueprints has the notion of key indices.

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices

Given your example, define a key index for "user", then query it with the key index.  Here's an example using OrientDB from a Gremlin prompt:

```
gremlin> g = new OrientGraph("memory://graph")
==>orientgraph[memory://graph]
gremlin> g.createKeyIndex("user", Vertex.class)
==>null
gremlin> g.addVertex([user:"Jason"])
==>v[#8:-3]
gremlin> g.addVertex([user:"Rick"])
==>v[#8:-4]
gremlin> g.stopTransaction(SUCCESS)
==>null
gremlin> g.V('user','Jason')
==>v[#8:1]
```